# Reward for doing useful computation

Tags: contract-development, tokens, ether, mining

I'm new to Blockchain. I'd like to design a system where solvers can solve real-world tasks initiated by the task owners. Miners are part of a cloud/cluster that provides resources. They verify and mine the smart contracts between the owners and solvers. But I also want the **miners and solvers** to be rewarded.
I'd like to be able to set the rewards percentage in the contracts themselves, then basically some tokens are paid by the owner and some tokens are mined. How would I implement such a network? Any references would also be appreciated.

Would it be possible to mine the contracts on a private network, and mine Ether on the public network in parallel, then distribute a portion of the mined Ethers to the task solvers? or shall I focus on creating my own reward and consensus mechanism (e.g. proof-of-useful-work)?

I'm just trying to find a feasible way to reward both solvers of the tasks (the solution providers) and the miners (the nodes in the resource provider cluster)

Comment: Check out the iExec project.

Comment: Thanks @RobHitchens. The project is relevant but includes a lot of unrevealed detailed. Let me put it this way. Shall I focus on creating my own reward and consensus mechanism (e.g. proof-of-useful-work) or shall I focus on validation of transactions on the public network and then distribute a portion of the mined Ethers to the task solvers? or do you think they can both be feasible?